# How to make a fluid image in Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make my images "fluid" in Bootstrap and change align to center?

Means that after changing browser resolution images don't fit the carousel borders and don't align.

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" >
<div class="item active">
  <img src="img/coffe.jpeg" alt="Coffee" width="460" height="365" a>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="img/sandwich.jpeg" alt="Sandwich">
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="img/wine.jpeg" alt="Wine">
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="img/sandwich.jpeg" alt="Sandwich">
</div>
</div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `class='img-responsive'` to the images, here is an [example](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_img-responsive&stacked=h)

Use the following css to align images center, by setting right and left margin to auto of the item direct child images, the images would align center.

```
  .carousel-inner > .item > img {
      margin: 0 auto;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you, But i`m trying to make a center align of image and full resolution in carousel borders. Can i do this without height and width parameters?